# How can I remove a background image or color from Flash-exported HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, flash, animation

I've done some animation using Adobe Flash CC, and then I exported it in HTML and JS, but I can't find the way to remove the background.

I see the function and all, but I don't know how to remove it.

Here is the html:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/tweenjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/movieclip-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Anime_V3.js"></script>

<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    images = images||{};
    ss = ss||{};

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
loader.loadFile({src:"images/Anime_V3_atlas_.json", type:"spritesheet", id:"Anime_V3_atlas_"}, true);
    loader.loadManifest(lib.properties.manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
    if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete(evt) {
    var queue = evt.target;
    ss["Anime_V3_atlas_"] = queue.getResult("Anime_V3_atlas_");
    exportRoot = new lib.Anime_V3();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init();" style="background-color:#D4D4D4">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1340" height="605" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

And I'm sorry for this, but the JS is just to big to fit in here, so I put it on pastebin, here is the link:

http://pastebin.com/fvqpMChM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around that allows you to make your canvas export with a transparent background. You can add this little piece of code to frame one in your actual flash file:

```
document.getElementById("canvas").style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255,0)";
```

What this does is target the canvas element when the piece is loaded by your user, and then change the background of the canvas piece from what ever your stage colour was to a fully transparent white. This should work properly in all browsers that support canvas, with the added bonus of not needing to change your file every time you export.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me.
Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: @JoeDimaggio Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

The background is added to the canvas as an inline style, based on the background color of your FLA. You can just remove the attribute.

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1340" height="605" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>

<canvas id="canvas" width="1340" height="605"></canvas>
```

Note that if you re-publish/export the content, it will overwrite your html, so you might want to turn that off in the publish settings.